# Why does this variadic function code produce random results on every run?

Tags: c, variadic-functions

As `double` and `unsigned long` are the same size, `va_arg` should pop the equal number of bytes from the stack and the value displayed should be the same every time the program is run since the `double` value doesn't change. But this is somehow not the case, and the value displayed is nowhere to be found in the neighboring memory cells.

Tested on gcc version 9.4.0.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void test(int num, ...)
{
    va_list arguments;                     
    
    va_start(arguments, num);           

    unsigned long x = va_arg(arguments, unsigned long);

    printf("%lu\n", x);

    va_end(arguments);
}

int main(void)
{
    double x = 1.234;

    printf("sizeof(double) = %zu\n", sizeof(x));
    printf("sizeof(unsigned long) = %zu\n", sizeof(unsigned long));

    test(1, x);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Behaviour is undefined if you provide wrong parameter type. The standard does not say anything about using a stack. Or how that stack would work. A compiler could provide different mechanisms for integers, floating point values or pointers. Having the same size does not make your code legal. Don't expect any specific result from undefined behaviour.

Comment: That's undefined behaviour. But the reason is probably because unsigned long is 32 bits on x86 architectures. Use unsigned long long, or even better uint64_t

Comment: @Elzaidir double and unsigned long are equal size on my machine. I was wondering too if it was trying to read out of bounds but this is not the case. Gerhardh thanks for the answer! Very interesting. I thought the va structure would just simply pass data around in a dumb way.

Comment: Different registers can be used for different types of arguments. So `x` can be sent in a floating point register, while `va_arg` tries to read from an integer register.

Comment: *`va_arg` should pop the equal number of bytes from the stack* 20 or 30 years ago, maybe.  But not today.  Today's ABI's tend to pass the first few arguments in registers, and the floating point registers are completely separate from the integer registers.

Comment: From my experiments, there is just some leftover left by printf function in %esi register, which _happens_ to be a pointer to the string literal. That register is then read by `va_arg`. Because of ASLR, the pointer is slightly different each run.

Answer (score 0):

> As `double` and `unsigned long` are the same size, `va_arg` should pop the equal number of bytes from the stack ...

No.
Argument passing mechanisms for different types are not specified by C to be the same nor from the *stack*.  <sup>*1</sup>

OP's code has *undefined behavior* (UB).

- Use `va_arg(arguments, unsigned long);` to get an `unsigned long`.
- Use `va_arg(arguments, double);` to get a `double`.

---

<sup>*1</sup> Advanced: Some common passing mechanisms  *may* exist for types pairs like `int/unsigned`, but that does not apply here.